# uncaught error todoDiv not defined Vanilla Js

Tags: javascript, appendchild, createelement

I am getting the following error in my todo list : Uncaught error todoDiv not defined. I am very new to this and am following a tutorial to build a todo list.
At the top of my script "todoDiv" element is created then used to append throughout then I try to append todoDiv and it tells me its undefined. How do I fix this so I can move forward?

```
//selectors
const todoInput = document.querySelector(".todo-input");
const todoButton = document.querySelector(".todo-button");
const todoList = document.querySelector(".todo-list");

//event listener

todoButton.addEventListener('click', addTodo);

//functions 

function addTodo(event) {
//prevent form from submitting

event.preventDefault();
```

```js
//Todo DIV
  const todoDiv = document.createElement('div');
  todoDiv.classList.add('todo');

//create li 
  const newTodo = document.createElement('li');
  newTodo.innerText = 'hey';
  newTodo.classList.add('todo-item');
  todoDiv.appendChild(newTodo);

//checkmark button
  const completedButton = document.createElement('button');
  completedButton.innerHTML = '<i class ="fas fa-check"></i>';
  completedButton.classList.add('complete-btn');
  todoDiv.appendChild(completedButton);

//trashButton
  const trashButton = document.createElement('button');
  trashButton.innerHTML = '<i class ="fas fa-trash"></i>';
  trashButton.classList.add('complete-btn');
  todoDiv.appendChild(trashButton);
  }

//append to list 
  todoList.appendChild(todoDiv);
```

```html
<Header>
  <h1>Heathers to do list</h1>
</Header>

<form>
  <input type="text" class="todo-input">
  <button class="todo-button" type="submit">
    <i class="fas fa-plus-square"></i>
  </button>

</form>

<div class="todo-container">
  <ul class="todo-list"></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I have tried changing from double to single quotes .. doesnt help

Comment: Are these called in functions? The orphan } at the end tells me there's a function or something and that todoDiv isn't in scope of where you're trying to access it. Quotes dont matter.

Comment: typo on `//trashButton` finished by `}`

Comment: Here's a reproduction https://jsfiddle.net/pdq4sf6v/1/

Comment: Sorry I chopped the top part off. I have edited to show the full code in addition to Html . Thanks!

Comment: HTML error : you add a `<div>` instead of  `<li>`, and add a  `<li>` inside a`<div>` whitout  `<ul>`  or `<ol>`

Comment: Thank you Phix !!  Such a silly mistake. I was so busy watching for everything else, I missed the simple !!